# Programmatically getting the iPhone's carrier signal strength

Tags: iphone, signals, cellular-network

Is there a way to get the iPhone's carrier, and/or the current signal strength, using Objective-C?  I know how to determine if a data connection is present, and whether or not that connection is wi-fi vs. cellular.  I also know that you can manually place the iPhone into "field test" mode by going to the phone app, and dialing #3001*12345*# and hitting Send.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

You made me curious and I found out that it's actually `*3001#12345#*` (hashes and stars exchanged).

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't pass Apple's review, but you can use CTTelephony notifications.
First, link against CTTelephony.
Now just use this:

```
static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {

    CFShow(name)

    NSString *sName = name;
    if ([sName isEqualToString:@"kCTIndicatorsSignalStrengthNotification"]) {
        if (userInfo) CFShow(userInfo);
    }    
}
```

And this to subscribe:

```
id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(); 

    CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(
                                 ct, 
                                 NULL, 
                                 callback,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL,
                                NULL);
```

Comment: Why does it won't pass review?

Comment: Despite CoreTelephony being a public API since iOS 4.0, CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault() and CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver() are private methods. It might pass review, depending on the reviewer, but it shouldn't.

Comment: I just tried this and it gave me messages about UI events (UIViewAnimationDidStopNotification, for example) but nothing Telephony-ish.  Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What iOS version are you using? Did you linked your project with CT?

Comment: Actually, disregard my last comment.  I just didn't wait long enough - the signal strengths don't come as often as I was expecting.