# Reading iPhone carrier's signal strength

Tags: ios, iphone, signal-strength

Is this even possible?
If not I'm really surprised this hasn't been open thru the API yet.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit too quick there with the duplicate :(

Comment: You can always make a screenshot (using `UIGetScreenImage()`) and then use some heuristic to determine the number of bars…

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Very creative approach :-)

Comment: this is method int result = CTGetSignalStrength(); in coretelephony but it not run with IOS 8.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically getting the iPhone's carrier signal strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270098/programmatically-getting-the-iphones-carrier-signal-strength)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow the use of low level network/wifi/cellular api's. Interestinlgy during a previous period, there were apps in the app store that made use of private apis (a few WIFI-Scanners for example). They've all been banded from the appStore by now, as far as I know at least.

Also the newly available (since iOS 4) core telephony framework doesn't offer any methods or properties to serve you the information you're looking for.

So unless you're building a non-app-store-app I don't see a legitimate solution to your problem.

*sam

Answer (score 1):

Several apps in the app store use OS 3 and get signal strength.
Apple fully approves them.

Comment: The existence of apps on the App Store does not necessarily means "Apple" approves of them.  It means that a particular reviewer approved it, which might be against the overall Apple policy.  In those cases, the apps usually get pulled from the store quickly.  But, it certainly is possible for apps to use private APIs and get approved.  There are techniques to obscure such usage that apparently sometimes get through the review process.  But, that's usually a short-term mistake on Apple's part.