# How to access Signal strength in iPhone for Jailbreak

Tags: iphone, signals, jailbreak, signal-strength

I am working on an iPhone project related "Create call log with Signal Strength". So we must get required RXQual, RXlevel, FER, C/I values. This app will support for jailbreak.

But I am unable to get any information to access these exact values. I can't go ahead without these values & unable to deliver the project to Clients.

Please suggest & guide me, How can I access these values. Its very urgent.
 Can you suggest me the private API's for getting access the signal strength values?

Comment: Is it even possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279163/reading-iphone-carriers-signal-strength

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've included the tag "jailbreak", so I imagine that the use of only public apis is a non-issue for you. But for future people coming to this question, there is no way at all to get these values through public (i.e. app-store-legal) methods.