# How to get the iPhones GSM signal level?

Tags: iphone

For an application I'm developing I need to get the GSM signal level, but I haven't been able to find how to do it using public APIs. I thought that it couldn't be done, but I have found an app on the itunes store that does it ([here](http://itunes.apple.com/app/no-signal/id366168900?mt=8)). Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to do it programatically, but if you type *3001#12345#* in the dial menu you can see it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically getting the iPhone's carrier signal strength](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270098/programmatically-getting-the-iphones-carrier-signal-strength)